# using font file in wpf usercontrol

Tags: wpf, fonts, elementhost

I am using a WPF UserControl inside a Winforms form.  I have it working.

I would like the text that I use in the WPF UserControl to use a font that I have as a TTF.

I do not know how to reference this TTF and have the control use it.  I am assuming I should load the TTF (this is not an installed font) in the UserControl and tell the control (a label) to use it but I only see reference to the font-family.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to load a font in wpf  from a TTF font file

```
<TextBlock FontSize="48" FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/Algeria.TTF#Algeria"  FontWeight="Normal">test value</TextBlock>
```

Use a Resource to store the font...

[image]

Comment: This is the line of code I am using              <Label FontFamily="firaSans-Medium.ttf#firaSans" x:Name="TopText" Content="Memory              Disk              Registry            System           Program" FontSize="3" Margin="0,-2,0,0" />  It does not work.  The file is in the same folder as the bin/debug

Comment: Still no  <Label FontFamily="/Resources/firaSans-Medium.ttf#firaSans" x:Name="TopText" Content="Memory ... abbrev.    The font is in the Resources folder.

Comment: Is your User Control in the same assembly as your main application? Man that is one small font.

Comment: It is in the same assemble,

Comment: Just went to git hub and downloaded the following font https://github.com/mozilla/Fira/blob/master/ttf/FiraSans-Medium.ttf I am not sure if this is the font you are using but the font name on this font is fira Sans Medium so the Xaml would look like .... <Label FontFamily="/Resources/firaSans-Medium.ttf#fira Sans Medium" x:Name="TopText" Content="Memory Disk Registry System Program" FontSize="3" Margin="0,-2,0,0" />

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the font name is correct ....

from git hub I found the following font
github.com/mozilla/Fira/blob/master/ttf/FiraSans-Medium.ttf. For this font the font would be fira Sans Medium so the Xaml would look like

```
   <Label FontFamily="/Resources/firaSans-Medium.ttf#fira Sans Medium" x:Name="TopText" Content="Memory Disk Registry System Program" FontSize="3" Margin="0,-2,0,0"/>
```